# Python double printed string

Tags: python

For some reason a string is double printed. How could it be like that?

[image]

Comment: too many prints, not enough text.

Comment: line 13 needs careful re-consideration. line 8 isn't doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The print statements are in the leap_year function, so every call to it will cause it to print either "Yes, …" or "No, …".

Here the first call happens at line 8, `leap_year(2020)`, and the second call happens when you call `days_of_the_month(2, 2020)` on line 16, which itself makes a call to `leap_year` on line 13.

It is generally good practice to not print from within a function, but rather return the status from the function and print outside. Hence you could just return `True` or `False` from `leap_year`, and run the following code to print:

```
if leap_year(2020):
    print("Yes, leap year")
else:
    print("No, not a leap year")
```

Comment: Oh yes of course! I forgot. I wanted to write 'return' instead of 'print.' Thank you.